# JPype and robotframework custom keywords

Tags: python, java, robotframework, jpype

I'm trying to use JPype with Robotframework to be able to use java-based SUTs.

I used this (https://forum.robotframework.org/t/connecting-java-with-robot-framework/5253) forum Post to implement it (modified it a bit to work with non-static methods) and it works well. However, I'm unable to create other functions in this JavaWrapper.py to use as keywords in my .robot file. The reason I want to do it, is to be able to use different arguments for the constructor of the java object for each test case.

My python code looks something like this:

```
def foo(self, name: str):
    do_something()
```

And in the robot file I'm using:

```
Foo    name
```

The error I'm getting is just `No keyword with name 'Foo' found.`. At the same time the keywords from the jar file are detected normally and I can use them without errors or warnings.

Comment: You left out semi-colon in foo function.

Comment: Right, I forgot it here. But in my actual code it's there, so that can't be the problem

Comment: Just in case, points to check first: 1. check that your class with the `foo` method is also named JavaWrapper, as the Python file. 2.  Does your robot file have the correct import of JavaWrapper.py? 3. there should not be red errors in the console while running your code.

Comment: @SamMaksymyshyn The foo method is in the same class as the other methods for getting the keywords from the jar files. The import in the robot file is definitely correct, because it works otherwise (the keywords from the jar are detected correctly). There's also no errors at all if I leave out the foo method

Comment: Hmm, maybe it would be useful to post your robot file + JavaWrapper.py here if possible.